# Fourier transform for diagonalizing the Hamiltonian of lattice

Tags: classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, field-theory, fourier-transform, vibrations

I am reading the first chapter of "Statistical Theory of Fields" by Kardar. There he discussed the idea of phonons.

Consider an ideal lattice at zero temperature with lattice vectors $\vec q^*(l,m,n)=[l\hat a+m\hat b+n\hat c]$

> Small fluctuations about the ideal positions (due to finite temperature or quantum effects) are included by setting $\vec q_{\vec r}=\vec q^*_{\vec r}+\vec u(\vec r)$. Thec ost of deformations in the potential energy is given by
> $V=V^*+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\vec r,\vec r',\alpha,\beta}\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial q_{\vec r,\alpha}\partial q_{\vec r',\beta}}u_{\alpha}(\vec r)u_{\beta}(\vec r')+O(u^3)$
> where the indices $\alpha$ and $\beta$ denote spatial components.

$(i)$
To find the normal modes we have to diagonalize this matrix of derivatives.
After that they are using the argument that "since the ground state configuration is a regular lattice, the elements of this matrix must satisfy various translational and rotational symmetries.
Thus, $\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial q_{\vec r,\alpha}\partial q_{\vec r',\beta}}=K_{\alpha,\beta}(\vec r-\vec r')$

$(ii)$
The translational symmetry allow us to atleast partially diagonalize the Hamiltonian by using Fourier modes.
$u_{\alpha}(\vec r)=\sum_\vec k \frac{e^{i\vec k.\vec r}}{\sqrt N}u_{\alpha}(\vec k)$
So, $\displaystyle H=V^*+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\vec k,\alpha,\beta}\Big[\frac{|p_{\alpha}(\vec k)|^2}{m}+K_{\alpha\beta}(\vec k)u_{\alpha}(\vec k)u_{\beta}(\vec k)^*\Big]$

$(iii)$
After that they are quantizing each oscillator, getting
$H=V^*+\sum_{k,\alpha}\hbar\omega_{\alpha}(\vec k)\Big(n_{\alpha}(\vec k)+\frac{1}{2}\Big)$
where $\omega_{\alpha}(\vec k)=\sqrt{\kappa_{\alpha}(\vec k)/m}$ and ${\{n_{\alpha}(\vec k)}\}$ are the set of occupation numbers.
Thus $E(T)=V^*+\sum_{\vec k,\alpha}\hbar\omega_{\alpha}(\vec k)\Big(\langle n_{\alpha}(\vec k)\rangle+\frac{1}{2}\Big)$

**Doubt**
$u_{\alpha}(\vec r)$ is the small fluctuation about the equilibrium position, right? Then why are we writing it as the superposition of fourier mode.
I know that if we have circulant matrix then its eigen vectors are discrecte Fourier Transform matrix (because the circulant matrix commutes with the shift operator). But here how the Fourier mode is diagonalizing the Hamiltonian.

I am completely not able to understand what is happening in $(ii)$ and $(iii)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have the 3-dimensional version of the circulant
matrix, which is a special case of Bloch's theorem.
Your $K$ commutes with translations by any lattice vector,
and those translations commute with each other. Just as in the
circulant case, since the eigenvectors of translations are the
plane waves, and in this case, none of their eigenvalues are degenerate, they
are the eigenvectors of $K$. If you write $u_\alpha(\vec r)$  as a linear
combination of these eigenvectors i.e. the Fourier expansion, the Hamiltonian
simplifies. In other words, you are just finding the normal modes in the
usual way by diagonalizing the spring constant matrix.

Because of the
translational symmetry of the lattice, you can at least block diagonalize
using the translation eigenvectors. In this case, where there is only
1 atom per unit cell, this fully diagonalizes the $K$ matrix.